# Reactjs - My redux is not storing the user

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to store a user using redux.
I want to then use the user's details to help filter data and also display on the navbar to show if logged in. I am able to maintain the user to stay loggen in by using sessions and cookies, no hitches there.

In redux, my store is being created succesfully and the user is properly being initialized to null before updating. However, on logging in, the user is not being updated in the redux store. Even after logging in the user stays null yet in my session, the user is logged in.

**index.js:**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./app/store";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
reportWebVitals();
```

**login_componenet.js:**

```
//import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";

function Login() {
  const [LoginID, setLoginID] = useState("");
  const [Password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [LoginStatus, setLoginStatus] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [logID, setLogID] = useState("");
  const [id, setId] = useState("");

  axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

  const login = (event) => {
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:8000/login", {
        LoginID: LoginID,
        Password: Password,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data.result[0]);
        if (response.data.message) {
          setLoginStatus(response.data.message);
        } else {
          setLoginStatus(response.data[0].UserFullName);
          setEmail(response.data.result[0].UserEmailID);
          setLogID(response.data.result[0].LoginID);
          setId(response.data.result[0].UserID);
        }
      });
  };

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(
      login({
        name: LoginStatus,
        LoginId: logID,
        email: email,
        id: id,
        loggedIn: true,
      })
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:8000/login").then((response) => {
      if (response.data.loggedIn === true) {
        setLoginStatus(response.data.user[0].UserFullName);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="auth-wrapper">
        <div className="auth-inner">
          <form onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}>
            <h3>Log In</h3>

            <div className="form-group ">
              <label>Login ID</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Login ID"
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setLoginID(e.target.value);
                }}
              />
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Password</label>
              <input
                type="password"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Password"
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setPassword(e.target.value);
                }}
              />
            </div>

            <button className="btn btn-primary btn-block" onClick={login}>
              Login
            </button>
          </form>
          <h1>{LoginStatus}</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

**store.js:**

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import userReducer from "../features/userSlice";

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    user: userReducer,
  },
});
```

**userSlice.js**

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState: {
    user: null,
  },
  reducers: {
    login: (state, action) => {
      state.user = action.payload;
    },
    logout: (state) => {
      state.user = null;
    },
  },
});

export const { login, logout } = userSlice.actions;
export const selectUser = (state) => state.user.user;
export default userSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my taste you should be `dispatch`ing information about successful login from `then` body of `axios` call. What you are currently doing is dispatching result of `login` call which is `undefined` (nothing is being returned from `login`).

Here's a link to redux docs on how dispatch works: https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#usedispatch

**EDIT**

Assuming we're still on the original code, if you did something like that all should work fine:

**login_component.js**

```
// import
>>> import { login as loginAction } from '<PATH_TO_USERSLICE.JS>' <<<


// where the login function is declared
  const login = (event) => {
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:8000/login", {
        LoginID: LoginID,
        Password: Password,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data.result[0]);
        if (response.data.message) {
          setLoginStatus(response.data.message);
        } else {
          setLoginStatus(response.data[0].UserFullName);
          setEmail(response.data.result[0].UserEmailID);
          setLogID(response.data.result[0].LoginID);
          setId(response.data.result[0].UserID);
>>>          dispatch(loginAction(response.data.user[0])); <<<
        }
      });
  };
```

*DISCLAIMER* Haven't actually run that but this should work.

Comment: I have tried your approach but now I have a new error that has come up.

Unhandled Rejection (Error): Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.

And this is happening in an infinite manner

Comment: create a sandbox, don't know what you have exactly changed. The error speaks for itself - you most likely must have passed something else than a plain object

Comment: All I did was lift the `dispatch` code from handleSubmit function and paste it in login function after setId(response.data.result[0].UserID).
Will you please eleborate more or even help me edit my code as I am a beginer hence taking time to understand.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-hill-kw41t?file=/src/index.js

Comment: @ChiragMaurya your sandbox is broken totally - it's incorrectly configured. Anyway, edited answer with suggested fix. Should you need more help, try fixing that shared sandbox first - this might help.

Comment: I am unable to notice the changes that you made, will you please elaborate more?

Comment: I marked differences with >>> and <<< at the end of line